# Strange issues with garage band 10 and sound fonts sf2

Tags: audio, music, garageband, midi

I'm having issues with Garage Band 10, when trying to set up custom sound fonts.
I installed them in `/Library/Audio/Sounds/Banks`

Then I opened the MIDI file, doing these steps:

- I select my track
- I choose Smart Control
- I select DLS Music Device like this:
  [image: DLS Music Device]
- Then it seems to work. I can see all my banks:
  [image: Banks working]
- But when I select the second track, doing exactly the same steps, I see another interface for DLS Music Device. With this one I can't select sound founts. Here's a screenshot:
  [image: DLS Music Device]

I can't understand the difference between the first and the second track.

What is causing this? How can I open the right interface I need?

Answer (score -1):

Have the same problem,
strange, but works once in a time (don't know the reason) : try it again after having created a different track without DLS